# Parametric representation of curves

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, real-numbers

If γ is a $C^1$ curve with parametric representation $φ: [a,b] → R^n$ (i.e. with φ ∈ $C^1$([a, b])) then $L(γ)= \int_a^b ||φ'(t)|| dt$.

I know this hold for $C^1$ but does it also hold for piecewise $C^1$?

Comment: Of course it does.  Just do the integral on each "piece" and add.

Comment: is there a link to a proof? thanks

Comment: The "proof" is exactly what I said: If f is piecewise C1 then the integral exists on each "piece" and the integral from a to b is the sum of those.